# Taxes with 1040 NR form

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident

A NR alien don't need to pay SSN and Medicare taxes, so my question is, would I have to pay these taxes in addition to Federal and State taxes? Or is there a form that I need to submit to my employer which will let them know that they don't need to deduct these taxes from my salary?

Paying SSN and Medicare taxes for one year and then filing for tax refund doesn't make sense to me.

Please let me know if anyone has experienced such problem.

Thanks

Comment: What State in the US are you residing in while you have nonresident alien status?

Comment: California State.

Comment: "A NR alien don't need to pay SSN and Medicare taxes" Only an NR in certain statuses.

Comment: "Paying SSN and Medicare taxes for one year and then filing for tax refund doesn't make sense to me." In fact, filing an income tax return does not allow you to get it back.

Comment: To add to the above comment - not only it doesn't allow *you* getting it back, it doesn't allow the *employer* getting it back either, and employers really don't like paying stuff they don't have to.

Comment: Just to clarify, I fall under that status where I don't need to pay SSn and Medicare. So I should go with  W-8 as someone suggested below?

Comment: @John: Does just telling them you are exempt, perhaps with a link to an IRS page, not work?

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't have these taxes withheld if you're exempt. You're showing your exempt status to your employer through the W8 form you must submit before getting paid.

Not all non-residents are exempt from FICA, though. Check the SSA site for the details.

Also, CA have their own version of FICA which you will still have to pay.